# JavaFX mouse transparent window for Mac OSX

Tags: java, macos, user-interface, javafx

I've looked everywhere and can't seem to find a solution to make a click through window in Java for OSX.

A transparent window in JavaFX is mouse transparent in Windows but not OSX.

It is probably an issue with how the OS handles windows but is there a way around this?

Here is what I'm doing:

I made a transparent window with a dashed border to indicate it's there.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpXvr.png - I'm unable to direct link images due to low reputation.